# Python: Execute a command in a subshell without cmd interface or hidden or in background

Tags: python, cmd

I would like to know how I could execute a command whitout appears the cmd window.
My code is in Python and the O.S. is Windows7.

The problematic line is:
`os.system(pathandarguments)`

The program works fine, execute the given path with the arguments but I loose the control of my program because my program window minimizes, I see cmd window a seconds and then my window program dont maximizes.

I want to execute the string pathandarguments without minimize my principal window. I prefer, if its possible, dont show cmd window.
I tried differents ways to make this:

`os.system(pathandarguments)` = works fine but minimizes my program window.

`os.popen(pathandarguments)` = `ERROR: CThread::staticThread : Access violation at 0x77498c19: Writing location 0x00000014` (Don't work)

`subprocess.Popen([pathandarguments], shell=False)` = Exception in python script's onAction (Don't work)

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
@martineau, The problem is not that I cannot import process, revising the log of my app I saw the problem is with import process at line 146:

```
13:42:20 T:4116 M:2156859392  NOTICE: import win32api
13:42:20 T:4116 M:2156859392  NOTICE: ImportError
13:42:20 T:4116 M:2156859392  NOTICE: :
13:42:20 T:4116 M:2156859392  NOTICE: No module named win32api
```

I dont have module win32api.

Comment: The shell=False is probably the nearest but what do you mean by the python scrip's onAction?

Comment: I tried too: subprocess.Popen([sacarThumb], shell=True) = The program don't do anything. My python script have a button and, when I click button, execute the code of the function that has the line os.system(pathandarguments) or os.system(pathandarguments) or subprocess.Popen([pathandarguments], shell=False) ...

Comment: @Sam888: The OP says nothing about trying to execute a Python script without a cmd window appearing...which is what the link you provided is all about.

Answer (score 1):

For a long time I've been using an open source Python module for process control called *[process-python](http://code.google.com/p/python-process)*. The Project Status there says "In its current state it was used heavily in the commercial [Komodo IDE](http://www.activestate.com/komodo) project." It's multiplatform, but one of the main reasons I started using it was because on Windows it will spawn a process without a console window. It's very simple to use. Here's a trivial example:

```
import process

p = process.ProcessOpen([eventfilepath]) # open text file with associated program
ignored_exitstatus = p.wait()
```

Hope this helps.