# How to launch a file with its default application using Python for WIN32, WIN64 and MAC OSX?

Tags: python, launch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Open document with default application in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434597/open-document-with-default-application-in-python)

I want python code to launch a file with its default application

e.g. a .txt file with notepad(when notepad is set as the default application to open .txt files)
I want to do this for WIN 32 bit, WIN 64 bit and MAC OS X

Please help me out

Answer (score 0):

Well it might seem awkward but following works quite well under Win Xp:

```
import webbrowser

webbrowser.open("myFile.txt")
```

Comment: From the docs: "Note that on some platforms, trying to open a filename using this function, may work and start the operating system’s associated program. However, this is neither supported nor portable." So +0: I don't think this is quite right, but I don't know what the best solution is.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about OS X, but an `os.system` call with  the file name as an argument works on Windows.

Also take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3729061/python-execute-a-command-in-a-subshell-without-cmd-interface-or-hidden-or-in-ba/3729627#3729627) answer.